# Catch array combine warning and print own error message?

Tags: php

I read some csv file and map the contents to the field names using array_combine:

```
$csv = array();
$a = array('some fields');
$b = array_combine($a, $csv);
```

However if the field names in $a are different from what I specified in my csv file the method will fails with a warning

> array_combine()
>   [function.array-combine]: Both
>   parameters should have an equal number
>   of elements

I tried using try and catch but this does not work. As a note, I am working with zend framework.

Any ideas how to catch the warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab the number of columns in the CSV and then compare it to `$a`'s length. Since you didn't specify, I'll assume the array is one dimensional with each line from the CSV file.

```
if (count($csv) > 0 && count($a) == count(explode(',', $csv[0]))) {
    // Valid
} else {
    // Not valid
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$b = @array_combine($a, $csv);
if (!$b) {
    // error!
}
```

You *should not* (ab)use the [`@` operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php), but in this case it does most literally what you want.

Comment: Simplest solution. Only issue is you won't know why it didn't work.

Comment: True. `!$b` may be either because the arrays were empty or because they were of different lengths. If you're really interested you can do a `if (count($a) != count($csv))` to output the right error message.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](http://us.php.net/array_combine) if either array is empty or if they are of different lengths, array_combine will return false.

So you should be able to do something like:

```
if($b = array_combine($a, $csv)) {

} else {
   ... the warning occurred ...
}
```

Comment: True, but I think he's trying to prevent the warning from being thrown at all.